# CSS display none only functions after timeout despite located inside document on ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am experiencing some peculiar behavior for setting `display` to `none`

Here is the core problem (I don't have a jsfiddle since I couldn't reproduce the problem in jsfiddle)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        jQuery('<li />')
           .attr("id", i)
           .attr("class", "toggle_test")
           .appendTo('ul');
        if (i >= 5){
            $("#".concat(i)).css("display", "none"); // doesn't work
            $("#".concat(i)).hide();                 // doesn't work
            $("#".concat(i)).css("color", "red");    // works
        }

    }
});
```

As you can see, setting the `display` to `none` or hiding it doesn't work while setting the css color works, which doesn't quite make sense.

I ran a couple of different test.

1. I found out that if I try `$("#1").css("display", "none");` in console it works
2. If I wrapped the if statement in another `document ready`, it still doesn't work
3. If I add a timeout.

**Code:**

```
if (i < 5){
    setTimeout(function(){
        // tested selecting class or id, below shows selecting class
        jQuery(".toggle_test").css("display", "none");  // works if timeout more than 1350
        jQuery(".toggle_test").css("color", "red");  // always works
    }, 2000);
}
```

it only works if the timeout is greater than `1350`, I am not sure what is the issue, can someone give me some advice?

Comment: If you can not reproduce it in a fiddle, than what else is running on your page?

Comment: You have typo right here `for(var i = 0; i < 10, i++)` . This should be `for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)` , which is probably not the problem, but hey.

Comment: As pointed out by @Ahmad below `$("#".concat(i))` is not the same as `$("#1")`  when `i=1` - just change into `$("#" + i)` as the way to join strings

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you're passing the jQuery selector *an array*. [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) joins a value into an *array* and returns the new modified array. Hence, returning a value like `['#', 1]` and so on.

In order to *query* an element as in your case, you just need to concatenate the *iterator's* value like you'd normally do with *strings*.

```
 $("#" + i).css("display", "none");
```

**Note:** *You have a typo as pointed out in the comments by @DavidDomain, which indeed should be `for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) ...`.*

Answer (score 0):

I've just ran into the same issue. My solution was to use classes instead

```
.hidden{display:none !important;}
.shown{display:block !important;}
```

It wasn't working without important.

Then do

```
$("#".concat(i)).addClass('hidden');
```

Comment: If it only worked with `!important` you might have had a rule in your CSS wich forced it to `display: block;` and had a higher specificity. The `!important` just forced the `display` to work as needed. That's actually the answer.

Comment: I believe if you don't specify anything, block is the default. But in our case, creating content on page ready, it seems that you would still have to force it (at least here I had to) cause it will discard it if you don't have any display rules

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery alternative, would be to use the `.toggle()` method.  That way, you will avoid W3C compliance issues.

As noted by Ahmad:

```
$("#" + i).toggle();
```

[jQuery Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)
[jQUery slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

Regarding the issue with the `setTimeout()` and `document.ready` specifically, I have found, in my experience, that the `setInterval()` JavaScript function is more useful and practical than `setTimeout()` primarily because you can use it as a "page sniffer" to detect when it should fire, and then turn it off after it does what it was programmed to do using `clearInterval()`.

One common practical use for `setInterval()` that I use it to detect DOM elements that can be modified by the user.
[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/n0hwa0pu/6/)